# If $\exists$ a surjection from nonempty set $A$ onto $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+})$, then $A$ is uncountable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I wanted to show this to use it in some other proofs.  I believe it holds.  My questions are, if this proposition is true and if the proof sufficiently shows it holds.

**Background**

From a previous proof, it uses the result that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+})$, the power set of the positive integers, is uncountable.

Theorem 7.1 nonempty set A is countable $\iff\exists$ a surjective function $h: \mathbb{Z_+} \to A$ (citation: Munkres Topology Chapter 7)

**Proof by Contradiction:**

Let $A$ be a nonempty set and suppose $A$ is countable.

Assume $\exists$ a surjective function $h: A \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+})$. Since $A$ is countable, $\exists$ a surjective function $f: \mathbb{Z_+} \to A$, by Theorem 7.1.

Consider the composition $h\circ f: \mathbb{Z_+} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+})$.  Since $f$ and $h$ are surjections, it follows that $h\circ f$ is a surjection ($c\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+}) \Rightarrow \exists a\in A$, such that $c = h(a) \Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{Z_+}$, such that $c = h(f(n))$.

This implies that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z_+})$ is countable, by Theorem 7.1, a contradiction.  Hence, $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: yes and yes!!!!

Comment: Excellent.  It seems so, but I was not sure.  It is actually a useful fact for several problems in Munkres book.  Thank you.